# Todas las posibles soluciones de un sistema de ecuaciones en R

Tags: r

Tengo el siguiente sistema de ecuaciones:

```
x+y+z=20
z-y>0
y-x>0
```

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera en R de enumerar todas las posibles soluciones para x,y,z y poder guardarlas en una matriz (3,m), donde m representa el número de soluciones posibles.

Comment: ¿Que has realizado de esto? es importante leas [ask] para formular adecuadamente una pregunta e nel sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Todas las posibles soluciones te diría que no se puede, lo que sí, puedes calcular algunas de estas soluciones armando una combinación de valores y probando las restricciones, por ejemplo:

```
# Creamos una función para validar las restricciones
fnvalid <- function(x) {
    # x+y+z=20
    # z-y>0
    # y-x>0
    if (x[1]+x[2]+x[3] == 20 &
        -x[2]+x[3] > 0 &
        -x[1]+x[2] > 0) {
        return(TRUE)
    }
    return(FALSE)
}
```

Luego generamos una matriz de `3xN` con combinaciones de valores enteros para cada variable, el tamaño es a gusto del consumidor.

```
m <- as.matrix(expand.grid(lapply(numeric(3), function(x) c(-10:10))))
```

En este ejemplo generamos todas las combinaciones de números enteros entre -10 y 10 para las tres variables. Por último aplicamos la función por fila para validar las restricciones y obtenemos los valores que cumplen con todas las condiciones:

```
m[which(apply(m, MARGIN=1, fnvalid)),]
```

En este ejemplo, el resultado sería:

```
     Var1 Var2 Var3
[1,]    5    7    8
[2,]    5    6    9
[3,]    4    7    9
[4,]    3    8    9
[5,]    4    6   10
[6,]    3    7   10
[7,]    2    8   10
[8,]    1    9   10
```

Comment: He encontrado una forma de hacerlo general, siguiendo algunos pasos que dijiste:
Sea N el valor total de la suma de las M variables:
`fnvalid <- function(x,b) {
  # x+y+z=b
  # z-y>0
  # y-x>0
  if (sum(x) == b &
      !is.unsorted(x) & anyDuplicated(x)==0) {
    return(TRUE)
  }
  return(FALSE)
}`

Las combinaciones las generaría como indicaste:

`m <- as.matrix(expand.grid(lapply(numeric(M), function(x) c(1:N))))`

y por último aplicamos al función por fila:

`m[which(apply(m, MARGIN=1, fnvalid,N)),]`